# How to run a on change function also without on form load

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a form with multiple steps and a function which check the date of a input field on step 2. If the date is longer than X months the user can't go to step 3, the function disable the next button.

But this function works with a change event and if the user goes one step back (to step 1) and after that to step 2 the function doesn't run till the user change the input field and if the user doesn't change, the user can go to step 3 with a wrong date.

```
function functionTest(){
  if (thereIsMissingValue())
        return

  let formDate = getFormDate()
    let comparisonDate = getComparisonDate()
    let formNewDate = getNewDate()

    let isOlderThanComparison = formDate < comparisonDate
    let isNewerThanToday = formDate > formNewDate

    if(isOlderThanComparison) {
      $('#next_button').prop('disabled', true);
      console.log('test');
    }else if(isNewerThanToday) {
      $('#next_button').prop('disabled', true);
      console.log('test2');
    }else {
      $('#next_button').prop('disabled', false);
      console.log('test3');
    }
}


$('#input1').change(function(){
    functionTest();
});
```

How can I ensure that this function also works without a change event?

I still fix it now by disable the previous button. added the previous button to the condition. Not the best option but it works.

Comment: you need to call the function on the click of that button/tab through which you are moving back/forward

Comment: @AlivetoDie yes I tried to run it on a click event like:

$('#next').click(function() {
  functionTest();
});

even if I use a click event, the user can continue ..

Comment: use `return false;` inside condition

Comment: If it is to stop a user from proceeding to step 3, why not just call it when the user clicks on the button that takes them to step 3? prevent the default action of the button if the validation is false and then they cannot proceed to step 3

Comment: I tried it with:
$('#next_button').click(function(){
    calculate();
});

The function runs but the user can still go to step 3 with a wrong date.

Comment: @can  now from where `calculate();` comes into picture? isn't we talking about `functionTest();`

Comment: you can use this `$('#next').click(function() { functionTest(); });` if you use return in your `functionTest` after diabling button. other wise call this function in the code where you go to page2 from page1 after success

Comment: @AlivetoDie yes sure, it's functionTest();

But when I disable the button from default, this time I can't go to step 3 if the date is correct after going to step 1 and then 2

Comment: Sorry for the dumb question, but are you sure the date comparison is correct? I mean if at least the condition is the right one and is not going every time to the last `else` condition. Besides that, I think you need to run both events, `change` in the input and on `click` in the button

Comment: @HenriqueLimas the date comparison is correct. It works with the change event. The problem is that when the user goes back to step 1 and after that to step 2 they can go to step 3 with a incorrect date

Comment: @can just to understand is the same button for each step? Is it a single form with the logic of the step inside, or each step is a separate form?

Comment: @HenriqueLimas not the same button. each button has a own ID.

Comment: @can maybe on step 2 you can set the button disabled as default, and undisable it only if the input changes. UPDATE: The problem is that it seems they all have the same id, so jquery will update all the buttons with that ID. maybe you can define an unique id for each button step

Answer (score 0):

add `return` in you function then call this function on #next click

```
function functionTest() {
        if (thereIsMissingValue())
            return;

        let formDate = getFormDate()
        let comparisonDate = getComparisonDate()
        let formNewDate = getNewDate()

        let isOlderThanComparison = formDate < comparisonDate
        let isNewerThanToday = formDate > formNewDate

        if (isOlderThanComparison) {
            $('#next_button').prop('disabled', true);
            return false;
            console.log('test');
        } else if (isNewerThanToday) {
            $('#next_button').prop('disabled', true);
            return false;
            console.log('test2');
        } else {
            $('#next_button').prop('disabled', false);
            console.log('test3');
            return true;
        }
    }
```

now call this function on `#next` click date is correct it will return false and will not go to page 3

```
 $('#next').click(function () {
        if (!functionTest())
            return
    });
```

Comment: It shows the console log, but it doesn't disable the next button

Comment: does it go to 3rd page?

Comment: waht function are you calling on next button click?

Comment: $('#next').click(function () { functionTest(); }); 

calling functionTest

Comment: nope, I can still go to the next step. Must I remove the .change event and use only click?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/163722/discussion-between-can-and-zp-baloch).